# Adding count items to string replacer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below works but I am unsure about how to add a counter to the code. It replaces all instances it finds perfectly but how can I get a total of all items it finds within a string? It is part of a chat script I have been working on and want to convert text to smileys so I can limit how many smileys people can enter in to chat.
This is my code I am messing about with.

```
let look = convertToSmilies(MessageString);
var MessageString = look;
```

The function

```
function convertToSmilies(MessageString) {
        var replaceall = require("replaceall");
        var fltr = MessageString;
        fltr = replaceall("&gt;:D&lt;", "", fltr);
        fltr = replaceall(":C", "☹️", fltr);
        fltr = replaceall("O:-)", "", fltr);
        fltr = replaceall("}:-)", "", fltr);
        MessageString = fltr;
        return MessageString;
};
```

I am not even sure this is the best way to deal smileys for a chatroom because I have omitted loads from the code just to make it shorter for easy reading.  I am also not sure if doing it this way would slow down the chat because of all the searching it would have to do on the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using function for replace string

```
function convertToSmilies(MessageString) {

    var counter = 0
    MessageString = MessageString.replace(/&gt;:D&lt;/gm, function(){
         counter++;     
         return "";
    });

    MessageString = MessageString.replace(/C/gm, function(){
         counter++;     
         return "☹️"
    });

    MessageString = MessageString.replace(/O:-\)/gm, function(){
         counter++;     
         return "";
    });

    MessageString = MessageString.replace(/}:-\)/gm, function(){
         counter++;     
         return "";
    });
    return MessageString;
};
```

Comment: That throws an error in the Powershell window. {PS C:\xampp\chatserver> node index.js
before:&gt;:D&lt;&gt;:D&lt;
C:\xampp\chatserver\index.js:956
        MessageString = MessageString.replaceAll("&gt;:D&lt;", function(){
                                      ^
TypeError: MessageString.replaceAll is not a function
}

Comment: For some reason replaceAll does not seem to work with node.js but replaceall does but not in the same way.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I didn't see that replaceAll is not supported on node.js. I changed the solution to use RegEx

Comment: it works great but I needed to remove var from the beginning of var counter = 0, I am guessing it is because it is a numeric value and not a string variable? It does not like the back slashes in the search terms neither so I will have to omit those smileys which use them. The string uses dompurify to sanitize the string before I can do anything with the string so that is why some characters will cause problems. thank you for your help, I will put your name in the script credits if that is ok.